# Using OR to collapse logic in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to combine the logic for this code snippet in PySpark to reduce code repetition. Any guidance would be really appreciated:

```
col0 = when(visit[1] == '0', to_date(visit[0])).otherwise(None)
col1 = when(visit[1] == '1', to_date(visit[0])).otherwise(None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a destructuring assignment and a generator expression:

```py
col0, col1 = (when(visit[1] == c, to_date(visit[0])).otherwise(None) for c in '01')
```

Comment: Well, you haven't given a [mcve] so there's no way I can test it. What specifically is the problem?

Comment: Sorry was a syntax issue, this works. Thanks! Could you explain why `01` is in as a string?

Comment: Oh, no problem. When you iterate over a string in Python, you get the individual characters as strings. It's just a shorter way of doing `for c in ('0', '1')`.

Answer (score 0):

`col = {i: when(visit[1] == f'{i}, to_date(visit[0])).otherwise(None) for col in (1,2)}`

Note: For 2 columns you gain a single line, but the additional cost in terms of subjective code clarity exceeds the gain by far; the suggested solution is probably worth only for 3+ columns

Comment: That's correct, in such simple case `str(i)` is even better